# Bootstrap 768 resolution issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

my page is: http://hubnuti.kaloricketabulky.cz/ and is based on Twitter bootstrap. When I open it on iPad or iPad simulator page doesn't look like I supposed to. On 768 resolution in my chrome everything seems to be correct but not on tablet.
I try to changed min-width to 769 but nothing's happened. 
Could You please look at it and give me some tips?

Comment: what you have tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this tag in your `head` tag :-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```